# Is there a size limitation to chan pipe on commande line?

Tags: pipe, tcl

This is probably a very stupid question but why does this freeze on the CLI if the size of the file is over 65,536? If 64kb is the limit to a pipe in Linux, is it possible to send larger files through this set up to process them?

Does it have anything to do with the `-buffering` or `-buffersize`?

I ask because I have something more complex than `proc OutputFile` processing the data and I was trying to use this to test its performance and noticed that running it several times consecutively was generating different results, as if not reading all the data or the same length of data each time.

Thank you.

```
proc SendFile {sock filename} {
  set fp [open $filename rb]; 
  set size [file size $filename]
  chan puts stdout "size: $size";
  chan copy $fp $sock -size [expr {min(65536,$size)}]
  close $fp
  #flush $sock
}

proc OutputFile {sock} {
 chan puts stdout [chan read $sock]
}

lassign [chan pipe] rchan wchan
chan configure $rchan -buffering full -buffersize 4096 -blocking 0 -translation binary
chan configure $wchan -buffering none -buffersize 4096 -blocking 0 -translation binary
chan event $rchan readable [list OutputFile $rchan]

SendFile $wchan filename.ext

after 2000 [list set forever 1]
set forever 0
vwait forever
close $rchan
close $wchan
```

Comment: Pipes (whether between processes or made by `chan pipe`) have a limited size determined by the OS, often about 8kB. It is usually configurable from outside Tcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing to a non-blocking channel, if you try to write more data than it can currently accept, tcl buffers the rest and tries to write it later. The maximum internal buffer size is 1,000,000 bytes. So on large input files, it's better to do the copying incrementally, say using the event loop (Especially when you're already using it).

Consider this version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

# Called when `file copy` finishes; close both the from and to channels here
proc DoneWithFile {ichan ochan size args} {
    puts stderr "Done copying file. Copieed $size bytes."
    chan close $ichan
    chan close $ochan
}

# Set up an async `file copy` of the given filename to a channel
proc SendFile {sock filename} {
    set fp [open $filename rb];
    set size [file size $filename]
    puts stderr "size: $size"
    chan copy $fp $sock -command [list DoneWithFile $fp $sock]
}

# Copy from a chan to standard output when it's readable;
# could also use another `file copy`
proc OutputFile {sock} {
    set dat [chan read $sock]
    if {[string length $dat] == 0} {
        # Triggered after closing the pipe in `DoneWithFile`
        if {[chan eof $sock]} {
            puts stderr "Done reading from pipe"
            chan close $sock
            set ::forever 1
        }
    } else {
        puts stderr "Read [string length $dat] bytes from pipe"
        chan puts -nonewline stdout $dat
    }
}

lassign [chan pipe] rchan wchan
chan configure $rchan -blocking 0 -translation binary
chan configure $wchan -blocking 0 -translation binary
chan configure stdout -translation binary ;# Make standard output binary too
chan event $rchan readable [list OutputFile $rchan]

SendFile $wchan rand.dat

after 2000 [list set forever 1]
set forever 0
vwait forever
```

I think the freezing you're seeing might be from the `after 2000 ...` bit though; there's nothing else in your code to exit the event loop. The above exits it after it's done writing data read from the pipe to standard output.

Comment: Thank you. It took me awhile to understand. I got that `-command` moved this to the background and "took care" of it but not how it did so. After a bit I think I understand that this could also be fixed by setting up a `writable` event on $wchan but I haven't tried it yet because in the interim I just had the client send the data and found that it all worked fie and the issue was my "simulation" pipe. Thanks again.